# How to use pagination with files in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have a list of files that I have managed to display on a table. However, I realized that after awhile, these files would crowd up a page. Is there any way to paginate them? I have done pagination in another page but that uses a database. I am using Codeigniter.

Heres my View

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>NRIC</th>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Policy Number</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach($data as $row): ?>
<tr data-url="<?php echo $row['url']; ?>" data-policyno="<?php echo $row['policyno']; ?>">
 <td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['product']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['policyno']; ?></td>
<td><input type="button" class="retrievedoc" value="View"/></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My Controller

```
function index()
{   

    $this->load->helper('directory');
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->model('statement');
    $map = directory_map('./assets/data/');
    $nric = $this->session->userdata('nric');
    $count=0;

    $config = array();
    $config['base_url']=site_url('user/statements/index');
    $config['total_rows']=$count;
    $config['per_page']=5;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['data']['result'] = $this->statement->retrieve($nric);
    $data['data']['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links(); 

    $this->load->view('includes/user/header');
    $this->load->view('user/statements',$data);
    $this->load->view('includes/user/footer');
}
```

Model

```
public function retrieve($nric)
{
    $count=0;
    $map = directory_map('./assets/data/');
    foreach($map as $row)
    {
         $separate = explode('_',trim($row,".pdf"));
         if($nric == $separate[0])
         {
            $count++;
            $data['data'][] = array(
             'firstname' => $separate[0],
             'product' => $separate[1],
             'policyno' => $separate[2],
             'url'=> base_url().'assets/data/'.$row
             );
         }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

I've attached an image of what I'm getting

[image]

Comment: I have added a answer with pagination with files you can test it out if you want

Comment: What is this $this->session->userdata('nric'); var_dump results for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you've got enough experience in CI pagination but because you deal with files instead db maybe it confuses you a bit.

To deal with the files you need to create a function with parameters(offset, limit) and return an array with total rows and data.

```
function getFiles($offset, $limit) {
 $count = 0;
 $start = $offset - $limit;
 $result = array();

 // get files from directory

 // foreach files and fill array like

 if ($count >= $start  && $count < $offset) {
 $result['data'][] = array(
         'firstname' => $separate[0],
         'product' => $separate[1],
         'policyno' => $separate[2],
         'url'=> base_url().'assets/data/'.$row
  );
 }
 // increase count
 $count++;

 // end foreach

 $result['total_rows'] = $count;

 return $result;
}
```

with the above function you will get the total count of files and also an array of a number of files in depends the offset and limit that you set.

In the if inside the foreach, based on the offset, limit and comparing the count then you fill the array with the right files.

example:

offset = 30
limit = 10

You have to get files from 20 to 30, `if count >= (30-10) && count < 30`, then you get 20,21,22...29

So 10 files!

If it was offset = 10, limit = 10, then 0,1,2...9

10 files again!

finally you setup the pagination as you know and vuala!

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/index.php/test/page/';
$config['total_rows'] = $result['total_rows']; 
$config['per_page'] = 10; // your limit

$this->pagination->initialize($config); 

echo $this->pagination->create_links()
```

Answer (score 1):

In Controller for getting the list:

```
function all_deal($pagi='10',$sortField='id',$order='DESC',$start='0')
{
    $filters = array();
    $start = $this->uri->segment(6);
    $data = $this->deal_model->get_all_deal($filters, $sortField=$sortField, $order, $start,$pagi);
    $page =($this->uri->segment(6))? $this->uri->segment(6):0;

    $config                      = array();
    $config["base_url"]          = base_url() ."index.php/deals/all_deal/".$pagi.'/'.$sortField.'/'.$order;
    $config["total_rows"]        = $data['count'];
    $config["per_page"]          = $pagi;
    $config["uri_segment"]       = 6;
    $config['use_page_numbers']  = false;
    $config['next_link']         = 'Next';
    $config['prev_link']         = 'Previous';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $paginglink =$this->pagination->create_links(); 

    $this->load->view('deal_list',array('data'=>$data['data'],'paginglink'=>$paginglink,'pagi'=>$pagi,'sortField'=>$sortField,'order'=>$order,'start'=>$start,'totalcount'=>$data['count']));
}
```

In Model:

```
function get_all_deal($filters,$sortField, $order, $start,$limit)
 {
    if($limit==''){
            $pagi='10';
        }
        $limit = (int) $limit;
        $start = (int) $start;
        $date1=date('Y-m-d');
        $this->db->select("SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS deals.*", false)
                ->from('deals');
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);

        $this->db->order_by($sortField.' '.$order);
        $data['data'] = $this->db->get()->result_array();
        $last_query =  $this->db->last_query();
        $data['count'] = $this->db->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as num_rows')->first_row()->num_rows;

        return $data;
 }
```

In View after the listing table in last create new table row or`<tr>` and in it `<td>` and then use this:

```
<span style="color:#000">Showing</span>
                    <?php 
                    echo $start+1; 
                    ?><span style="color:#000"> to</span>
                    <?php
                     $uri=$this->uri->segment(6);
                     if($uri)
                     {
                        $records=$uri+$pagi;
                        if($totalcount<$records)
                        {
                            echo $totalcount;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo $uri+$pagi;
                        }

                     }
                       else
                        {
                            echo $pagi;
                        }
                    ?> <span style="color:#000">of</span>
                    <?php echo $totalcount; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $paginglink;?>
```

Hope you can use it easily. Good Luck!

Comment: Um..I see that this uses the database in the model. I'm actually just counting files in a directory and I just want to paginate the results. So far the results are out already. No idea how to paginate them only.

Comment: its simple you can change the code.  here actually the model fetch data according to the need of results per page so i use this code style every time.  You can try this now and if you find any other easy approach you can use it then. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have a working pagination for my image files but you can do the same for you pdf files. Currently I have used query strings for my pagination. But you can convert that to [URI Segments](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#uri-segments) if you want to.

You may need to set [URI Routes](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) if your not going to use query string

Note: you may have to set some routes

Feel free to try it out.

```
<?php

class Filemanager extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $directory = scandir(FCPATH . 'assets/data', 1);

        $files = array_diff($directory, array('.', '..'));
        $files_count = count($files);

        // Set your displayed limit.
        $files_limit = 2;

        // The input get you could rename to a uri segment if not using query string
        $input_get_per_page = $this->input->get('per_page');
        $input_get_per_page += $files_limit;

        foreach($files as $file => $value) {

            if ($file < $input_get_per_page && $file >= $input_get_per_page - $files_limit) {

                var_dump($value);

                // Your code here use 
                // Use $value to get filename.

            }

        }

        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['base_url'] = base_url('index.php?d=common&c=filemanager');
        $config['total_rows'] = $files_count;
        $config['per_page'] = $files_limit;
        $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
        $config['num_links'] = "16";
        $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
        $config['full_tag_close'] = "</ul>";
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
        $config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
        $config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
        $config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $this->load->view('filemanager_view', $data);
    }
}
```

How my config is.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI PROTOCOL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This item determines which server global should be used to retrieve the
| URI string.  The default setting of 'REQUEST_URI' works for most servers.
| If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors:
|
| 'REQUEST_URI'    Uses $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
| 'QUERY_STRING'   Uses $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
| 'PATH_INFO'      Uses $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
|
| WARNING: If you set this to 'PATH_INFO', URIs will always be URL-decoded!
*/
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

And

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Enable Query Strings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default CodeIgniter uses search-engine friendly segment based URLs:
| example.com/who/what/where/
|
| By default CodeIgniter enables access to the $_GET array.  If for some
| reason you would like to disable it, set 'allow_get_array' to FALSE.
|
| You can optionally enable standard query string based URLs:
| example.com?who=me&what=something&where=here
|
| Options are: TRUE or FALSE (boolean)
|
| The other items let you set the query string 'words' that will
| invoke your controllers and its functions:
| example.com/index.php?c=controller&m=function
|
| Please note that some of the helpers won't work as expected when
| this feature is enabled, since CodeIgniter is designed primarily to
| use segment based URLs.
|
*/
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';
```

Working Image 1 with my code

[image]

Working Image 2 with my code

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying. I've edited my code in the question and added an image. Will try your method and see how it goes.

Comment: Sorry, I was away for a week. Will try and let you know. By the way, I understand URI Routes, but what do you mean by query string?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code
on application/config/ folder
add paging.php

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
$config = array(
    'paging' => array(
        'full_tag_open'     => '<ul>', 
        'full_tag_close'    => '</ul>', 
        'prev_link'         => '&laquo; Previous', 
        'prev_tag_open'     => '<li >', 
        'prev_tag_close'    => '</li>', 
        'next_link'         => 'Next &raquo;', 
        'next_tag_open'     => '<li >', 
        'next_tag_close'    => '</li>', 
        'cur_tag_open'      => '<li><a class="active">', 
        'cur_tag_close'     => '</li>', 
        'num_tag_open'      => '<li>', 
        'num_tag_close'     => '</li>', 
        'last_link'         => 'Last &raquo;', 
        'last_tag_open'     => '</a><li>', 
        'last_tag_close'    => '</li>', 
        'first_link'        => '&laquo; First', 
        'first_tag_open'    => '<li >', 
        'first_tag_close'   => '</li>'
    )
);
```

in Controller function add the following code

```
$paging_config = $this->config->item('paging');
    $paging_config['uri_segment'] = 2;//uri segment 
    $paging_config['per_page'] = 5;//per page 
    $paging_config['base_url'] = site_url();//full of pagination function
    $this->pagination->initialize($paging_config);
```

in view add for pagination

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    $_total_rows=100; # call here dynamic total rows
    $url = base_url().'call-here-your-url'; # call here your url
    $per_page = 20; # change it from yours

    $get_url='&field1=value&field2=value'; # use here your parameters 


    $this->load->library('pagination'); 
    $config['base_url'] =$url.'?p=0'.$get_url;
    $config['total_rows'] = $_total_rows; 
    $config['per_page'] = $per_page;
    $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
    echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Controller use this code

```
$this->load->library("pagination");
$config["base_url"] = base_url() . "controller/function_name";
$config["total_rows"] = $total->num_rows();
$config["per_page"] = 1000;
$choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
$config["num_links"] = 3;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

//in view page
`<p><?php echo $links1; ?></p>
try this one`